How to use a non-static class member on all files?
Title. I need to access a class member that has to be non-static from another file. Example:
// a.cpp
#include "h.h"

int main() {
    B num1(1);
    B num2(2);
    
    return 0;
}

// b.cpp
#include "h.h"

int B::b; // has to be non-static
B::B(int n) {
    b = n;
}

// h.h
class B {
    public:
    int b;
    B(int);
};

Here, the non-static B::b needs to be accessed in a.cpp.
This, however, gives this error:
b.cpp:3:5: error: ‘int B::b’ is not a static data member of ‘class B’
    3 | int B::b; // has to be non-static
      |     ^

The only solutions I could find involved putting the variables in the header file to be static:
// h.h
class B {
    public:
    static int b;
    B(int);
};

Unsurprisingly, this is not what I want since it makes B::b static, and therefore makes num1 == num2.
So, how exactly do I do this? Is there even a way to do this?

int B::b;  is not how you initialize a non-static member.  A non-static data member(as well as a static member) have class-scope not global scope. I would highly recommend a good c++ book.

What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve. Global variables should be avoided. And as I said, the whole point of data "members" is that they have class-scope. That is why we call them members.

It looks like an XY problem. What is the actual issue you are trying to solve ?

We access a non-static data member by using the access operator . on an object of that class type. You can't just use/share a member variable directly to all files. You can however share an object of that class type across TUs.


How to globally use a non-static class member, declared in a header?

We just can't. Basically, data members(both static as well as non-static)  have class-scope not global scope. That is why they're called "member variables".
To use a non-static member, we need to have an object of that class type. Then we can use member access operator as shown below:
B obj;           //first create object of that class type
int i = obj.b;   //then access the data member using operator.

Non-static data members are usually initialized in a constructor's member initializer list or using default member initailizer.
I would also recommend a good c++ book

In essence, we can't just directly share a "member variable" across files. We can however share an object of that class type across TUs.

What technical limitation limits sharing non-static members but not static members, as seen with the example? (Or am I just misusing scope terms? I really shouldn't have said globally)

@MinersHaven Technically, we can't even share static data members just like non-static member. So your assumption that "sharing non-static members but not static members..." is wrong.We don't "share" static data members in the global sense(we do it in the class-scope/sense). We can just initialize them(static data members) in the same namespace in which the class-name appears. For accessing static data member we still have to write Classname::membername.

@MinersHaven The point is that for accessing non-static data member we need to have an object of that class-type and then we can use obj.membername. Or you can have a pointer to an object of the class type and then you can use ptr->membername. So sharing data members directly is not possible. You can however share an object of that class type. Though there shouldn't be any need to use global variables at all, especially not in the shown code.

@MinersHaven the issue of static and non-static members and their characteristics is really a very basic one. The link in the answer above contain a great list of good books that can explain these concepts.
